# How can I process SQL Server paginated query results in a C# loop / list

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT
DECLARE @RowsOfPage AS INT
DECLARE @MaxTablePage  AS FLOAT 

SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @RowsOfPage = 4

SELECT @MaxTablePage = COUNT(*) FROM SampleFruits
SET @MaxTablePage = CEILING(@MaxTablePage/@RowsOfPage)

WHILE @MaxTablePage >= @PageNumber
BEGIN
    SELECT FruitName, Price 
    FROM SampleFruits
    ORDER BY Price 
        OFFSET (@PageNumber-1) * @RowsOfPage ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY

    SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1
END
```

I have created 2 SQL Server paginated queries following the above sample script found at this link: [https://www.sqlshack.com/pagination-in-sql-server/#:~:text=What%20is%20Pagination%20in%20SQL,pagination%20solution%20for%20SQL%20Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/pagination-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Pagination%20in%20SQL,pagination%20solution%20for%20SQL%20Server).

I want to load their results in .NET lists, something like this:

```
List<Item> currentItemVersion = GetCurrentItemVersion();
List<Item> itemVersionHistory = GetItemVersionHistory();

foreach (Item myItem in currentItemVersion)
{
    if (myItem.IsGood == true) 
    {
        List<Items> goodItems = itemVersionHistory.Where(x => x.Item_ID == myItem.Item_ID).ToList();                
        
        foreach (Item ItemVersions in goodItems)
        {
            // DO SOME THINGS HERE
        }
    }           
}
```

In this C# code, lists `currentItemVersion` and `itemVersionHistory` have only the first 4 items returned by the first page of the underlying T-SQL paging query, so I can only process 4 items in my T-SQL's results first page.

How do I process all the items in the several pages returned by my underlying SQL Server paged queries?

Or is this actually the correct way of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here to be honest. But why are you using a float and treating it like an int? You should just use an int.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to paginate if you're still going to return all rows. Pagination values (page number and size) are usually passed into the query, data retrieved, and then you send another query for the next page.

Comment: And why are you using a loop in your query like this? It makes no sense at all. You would do yourself a favor by removing all the logic that does paging since you are just going to get all of the rows anyway.

Comment: You could simplify this whole iterative process to a single query. `SELECT FruitName, Price FROM SampleFruits ORDER BY Price`

Comment: If you want to process the paginated results you should use an `IEnumerable` and the `yield return` statement, other then that I'm with the rest, it doesn't seem like you actually need the paging.

Comment: @DavidG I'm honestly looking into this paging thing for the first time but your comment has given me some clue.